# Initialize AIDE in Slackware 14.2

Tags: configuration, configure, slackware, slackbuilds, aide

I have succesfully installed AIDE in my slackware installation. I want to initialiaze using the command below :

```
aide --init
```

But since I dont have the `aide.conf` file yet, I could not start the service. I dont know how to create that configuration file, and what items or lines of code it must contain.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration for the software is described in the manual: `man aide.conf`. There is also an example configuration in `/usr/doc/aide-$VERSION/README.Slackware`. Many contributed scripts exist in `/usr/doc/aide-$VERSION/contrib`. A copy of the example configuration (`/etc/aide.conf`) follows.

---

> I suggest that you start with the example below, use it for a few weeks,
>   and tune it to accommodate your habits.
>
> The media containing your aide databases should be physically
>   unmounted between scans. Alternatively, see /usr/doc/aide-$VERSION/contrib
>   for some example scripts that will help you gpg sign your database, for
>   online storage.

```
=== /etc/aide.conf sample ===
database=file:/mnt/usb/aide.db
database_out=file:/mnt/usb/aide.db.new
gzip_dbout=yes

/etc/ld.so.cache p+ftype+l+u+g
/etc/ntp/drift   p+ftype+l+u+g

/boot       R
/etc        R
/bin        R
/lib        R
/usr/lib    R
/usr/libexec    R
/usr/lib64  R
/lib64      R
/usr/bin    R
/usr/local/bin  R
/sbin       R
/usr/sbin   R
/usr/local/sbin R
=/var/log   R
```